# Native Windows Phone app vs Jquery Mobile + PhoneGap?

Tags: jquery-mobile, cordova, windows-phone-8, hybrid-mobile-app

I am new to mobile programming, and I want to build a mobile app to fill few forms, offline, and then sync them later, when internet access is available, with a database on an online server through a VPN connection.

At first, I thought about learning Windows8 Phone App development, but then I heard/read about Phonegap and Jquery Mobile! and I am a bit confused which one would be better to use, considering two things:

1- Which one you think would be good for my app's functionality
2- Which tool would be more beneficial on the long run (in the mobile programming world).

Any advice would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

With these functionality I don't thing you don't need many mobile dependent features rather you need more web features. For your first question, answer could be that technology in which you are more comfortable. But it also depends how you want to sync your data. In background or when the app is open. If you want to sync data in background that means app is closed, you have some data to send in server, and internet access is there, then you'll need some native windows phone code. In that case if you use phonegap ultimately you will need some native code to deal with it, may be you'll need to write a plugin to communicate between phonegap and native code. And if you don't need background process, if you want to send data to server only when your app is opened,phonegap can work like a charm. It'll be easy to communicate between 2 web technology.

For your second question, ofcourse phonegap is great technology to learn to deal with cross platform. If you need to make apps not only for WP rather for all platforms then phonegap is great. Having said that it's necessary to mention phonegap has it's quirks too. Native code always has it's benefit. Phonegap can't completely overcome native code. But if you are willing to compromise a bit, then it's easy to learn phonegap,a familiar tech than all those platform dependent techs like objective-c, android etc.
(N.B. I'm not an expert, it's just my experience so far)

Comment: Actually thats what I am planning on doing, syncing through the app only. And I am most likely going for phonegap. Thanks :)